# How have different tab bar icon color when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want know if there is a way to have a different color for different icon selected in a `UITabBarController`, i know that with this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

i can change the selection color for all icon, but how i can do it for different tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this, would be by simply changing the tint color of the tabbar in the different viewcontrollers.

Let's say for example you have 3 different tabs: `tab1`, `tab2` and `tab3`, all of which are displaying different viewcontrollers. Now, let's say you want to have a blue tint color in `tab1` but a red tint color in `tab2` and `tab3`. 
Then, you can simply add the following line to the `viewWillAppear:` method of the different `ViewControllers`.

For the first viewController, which is shown in `tab1`, you'd have:

```
//In your viewcontroller which is shown in tab1
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // change tint color to blue
   [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

And for the other two, you simply put another color:

```
//In your viewcontrollers which are shown in tab2 and tab3
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // change tint color to red
   [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

It's that simple. There are certainly other ways of doing this, but this one is pretty clean and straightforward.